# What do the makefile symbols $^ mean?

Tags: c, makefile

makefile:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(GCC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

What `$@` and `$^` exactly do in make file?

Answer (score 4):

`$^` is the set of dependent files used to build something else.

`$@` is the name of the target to be built.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

Answer (score 3):

$@ is the name of the target. This is quite useful when the target is a pattern rather than fixed.

$^ is the name of the prerequisite that caused the rule to execute.